# LINQ to SP Problem

Tags: linq, gridview

I have a following

```
var resultsMarks = from mItem in MItemList.ToList()
select new
{
    ScienceGroup = mItem.ScienceGroup,
    ArtsGroup = mItem.ArtsGroup,
    CommerceGroup = mItem.CommerceGroup,
    StudentID = mItem.StudentIDId
};

var detailtStudents = from student in SItemList.ToList()
select new
{
    Name = student.Name,
    Class = student.Class,
    Section = student.Section,
    Role = student.RoleNumber,
    Science = from result in resultsMarks where result.StudentID == student.Id select result.ScienceGroup,
Arts = from result in resultsMarks where result.StudentID == student.Id select result.ArtsGroup,
Commerce = from result in resultsMarks where result.StudentID == student.Id select result.CommerceGroup

};

gvCollated.DataSource = detailtStudents;
gvCollated.DataBind();
```

Now, the problem is in the Grid I am getting only - Name, Class, Section, Role. But no more fields like Science, Arts, Commerce. This is happening because these are coming as Collection objects, which can't be displayed on the Grid in that way.

I want to select those specific values, not as collection.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: I just placed FirstOrDefault() at the end of each nested LINQ. 

And it worked.

Thanks